# Montar um gerenciador de pacotes(NuGet) local

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Devido a um problema enorme que acontece aqui na empresa, como dependências de pacotes, então a empresa resolveu criar um `NuGet` privado, que roda localmente. O objetivo disso é quando qualquer pessoa baixar o código fonte de nossos aplicativos, ele já sinta a falta de alguma `DLL` e vai no diretório do `Nuget` e já faz a instalçaõ ou sugere a instalação da `DLL`. O problema é que eu não sei nem por onde começar. Alguém já fez isso?

Comment: Você quer montar o servidor privado, os pacotes, ou quer saber sobre ambos?

Comment: Para montar o repositório privado é só seguir esses passos.
https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, exatamente isso. O Leandro Angelo me passou um link que vpou dar uma olhada e ver se atende, mas aberto a sugestões.

Comment: Exatamente isso o que? Montar pacotes, hospedar um feed ou as duas coisas?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, então seria as duas coisas, porém o que se está pedindo é algo mais inteligente, ou seja, ele detectar a necessidade daquela dependência e instalar o pacote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se vocês vão utilizar somente interno, recomendo que crie uma pasta para os pacotes, não utilize um servidor de nuget, tivemos muitos problemas na empresa com isso.

1. Você deve criar os pacotes : o comando seria nuget.exe pack pasta\projeto.nuspec -OutputDirectory c:\nuget\pacotes.
2. Copie os arquivos gerados para um diretório de rede que todos tenham acesso.
3. Configure o VisualStudio para ler este diretorio. (TOOLS > NuGet Packege Manager > Packege Maneger Settins > Entre em Packege Manager > Package Sources. na parte inferior, informe o nome e o source, que é o caminho do seu servidor e clique em ok)
4. Pronto, agora você pode instalar seus pacotes. Lembre-se que todos da empresa, devem configurar o VisualStudio, para apontar para essa pasta de rede.

Comment: SrLopes, ok, mas há como eu baixar um projeto e esse projeto perceber que tem uma dependência e baixar do NuGet local as referências, ou pelo menos, informar? O que nós queremos é automatizar ao máximo.

Comment: As dependências são montadas no pacote, se você criar um pacote, você pode amarrar o seu outro pacote.
Algo do tipo:

 <dependencies> 
        <dependency id="RouteDebugger" version="1.0.0" />
  </dependencies>

Comment: Montei e está funcionando, mas gostaria de dar mais inteligência, mas o que eu quero é algo mais utópico, não creio que seria possível.